# Retrieve a href titles containing a specific string in url php

Tags: php

i have the following code. and i want to retrieve only the a href titles , that have /movie/ within url.

```
 function get_a_contentmovies(){
          $h1count = preg_match_all("/(<a.*>)(\w.*)(<.*>)/ismU",$this->DataFromSite,$patterns);
        return $patterns[2];
    }
```

Comment: Prepare for answers stating regular expressions should not be used for this :)

Comment: @Anne Stackoverflow should have a bot that specifically responds to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOMXpath like this:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href, '/movie/')]");

foreach($elements as $el) {
    var_dump($el->getAttribute('title'));
}
```

Comment: You should enable error_reporting(E_ALL); and check the output. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex to parse (x)HTML is a bad idea. You should use a DOM parser such as [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php). Have a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).